# Making ajax calls to get response from two javascript files to a single php file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am working with JQuery Ajax. The PHP file I require response from is on the server. The first JavaScript file is on the same directory on the server with PHP and the second file is saved with me locally which I am using inside my chrome extension. I have made a block of code in PHP, which I run through Ajax from local JavaScript file and get response, what I want is to get invoke the JavaScript on server , and can be solved by two methods.

1) To make Ajax call to same block of code of PHP, which saved in the same directory on the server.

2) Invoke the JavaScript on server from the local JavaScript file. When the local JavaScript get the response then use a method to invoke the JavaScript on server from this local one.

Basically I tried both of them, I have made a second Ajax call to same block of code, but as the server html file run first and load the JavaScript first, then It do not return anything from that Ajax request.
In the second method I have used postMessage API of chrome. But it blocks the cross origin message passing, from local to server. And the domain name conflicts stop passing my message to invoke the server JavaScript.

**Local file JavaScript that request data and get response**

```js
function sendUrl(url){
   console.log("Passed to sendURL : " + url); 
   $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
 url:"http://www.bitbaysolutions.com/connections.php?updateRow=true",
 data:{
  ajaxified : url
 },
 success:function(res){
          console.log("PHP RESPONSE " + res);
 }
   });
}
```

> I want to invoke the server JavaScript when I get response from this Ajax call. Simply on success.

**When I use post Message API in the same Ajax call response**

```js
function sendUrl(url){
   console.log("Passed to sendURL : " + url); 
   $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
 url:"http://www.bitbaysolutions.com/connections.php?updateRow=true",
 data:{
  ajaxified : url
 },
 success:function(res){
       console.log("PHP RESPONSE " + res);
         window.postMessage(res,"*");
 }
   });
}
```

**And write this code on server JavaScript file to receive the message**

```js
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

eventer(messageEvent,function(e) {
   console.log(e.data);
});
```

> After running it I get the following error :  `GET chrome-extension://jifdgpnmlcmlcbpmemiecblbddpdejhe/Row%20Updated net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

**Simply I would like to invoke the server JavaScript file when I get response on this local file. And if there is any other possible solution, I would appreciate that.**

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should be using [Chrome's Message](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) Passing instead of `window.postMessage`.

So your Javascript in the extension would look something like this:

```js
function sendUrl(url){
   console.log("Passed to sendURL : " + url); 
   $.ajax({
    method:"GET",
 url:"http://www.bitbaysolutions.com/connections.php?updateRow=true",
 data:{
  ajaxified : url
 },
 success:function(res){
       console.log("PHP RESPONSE " + res);
       chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
           chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {thisCameFromTheServer: res}, 
               function(response) {
                   //If your script on the page sends a response, 
                   // deal with it here.
                   //console.log(response.farewell);
               }
           );
       });
 }
   });
}
```

Your Javascript on the page that receives the message would have to be inserted as a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) by the extension, and that script can either manipulate the page directly, or call JS that's loaded from the server.

The Content Script would receive the message like this:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        
        if (request.thisCameFromTheServer) {
            console.log(request.thisCameFromTheServer);
        }
       /* I *think* that you have access to the whole page DOM, and any JS
       on the page, from here, so if there's a JS function you want to call
       that's on the page you probably can. */
    }
);
```

Comment: I cannot add this : 
> chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        
        if (request.thisCameFromTheServer) {
            console.log(request.thisCameFromTheServer);
        }
     
    }
);

Because the javascript I want to invoke is on the server, not local.

Comment: I am told that I can invoke a javascript function which is on server from the local javascript through ajax but don't know how to do that

Comment: Is the server javascript actually running on the server, in Node or something, or is it being served by the server as part of the web page, (so it's actually run by the browser)?

Comment: That is simple javascript , not node js etc. There is an html page which is controlled by the js file.

Comment: So then the Javascript is actually executed in the browser, so really you have 2 Javascript files executing in different places in the browser: One in the Extension, and on in the Web Page. Because of security rules the only way they can talk to each other is through Chrome's `sendMessage` APIs, (as in this answer).

AJAX isn't going to let you invoke the webpage JS from the Extension JS. 

What are you trying to do in the extension that can't just be done on the web page?

Comment: I did it, I made the login signup pages local, which I wished to make changes in